# Delete duplicate equal rows in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a table with duplicates rows, where all column values are equal:

```
+------+---------+------------+
|  id  |  value  | timestamp  |
+------+---------+------------+
| 1    |  500    | 2019-10-12 |
| 2    |  400    | 2019-10-11 |
| 1    |  500    | 2019-10-12 |
+------+---------+------------+
```

I want to keep one of those equal rows and delete the others. I came up with:

```
DELETE
FROM
  `table` t1
WHERE (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id),
  FROM
    `table` t2
  WHERE
    t1.id = t2.id 
) > 1
```

However this does not work:

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported
>   unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an
>   efficient JOIN.

Any ideas how to remove duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> ... where all column values are equal
>   So you can use simple `DISTINCT *` and instead of `DELETE` use `CREATE / REPLACE` to write back to the same table

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.table`   
PARTITION BY date
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

In `PARTITION BY` clause - you should add the fields you use to partition the original table